# how to pass arguments in curl command

Tags: shell, unix, curl

i am getting the below error while executing the curl command in unix. Not sure if this is the right way to put the arguments in curl. Can you please advise on this?

> `curl -X POST -H Authorization:'Bearer AAEAAJ6ZNfGbzJkSuJ1o5rXLBec5Q' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d {"Filter": {"ClientName": "ABC","WorkflowName": "sk_lask"},"SortingName": "StartDate","SortingOrder": "Desc"} http://someaddress.com/api/status/search HTTP/1.1`

error

```
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace at pos 13
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ABC,WorkflowName; Unknown error
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 9
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: StartDate,SortingOrder; Unknown error
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 5
```

Comment: Quote your payload: `-d '{"Filter": {"ClientName": "ABC","WorkflowName": "sk_lask"},"SortingName": "StartDate","SortingOrder": "Desc"}'`

Comment: @anubhava tried that now it got stuck.no response

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote your header, payload and also remove `HTTP/1.1` from end as this command:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer AAEAAJ6ZNfGbzJkSuJ1o5rXLBec5Q' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"Filter": {"ClientName": "ABC","WorkflowName": "sk_lask"},"SortingName": "StartDate","SortingOrder": "Desc"}' \
'http://someaddress.com/api/status/search'
```